# $post->ID calls for current page, but what is the code to call for any new page created and published in WordPress?

Tags: php, posts

While there may be another or better way to do it, all I need is this last snippet to make this do exactly what I need. So, I hope anyone here can and is willing to help me get it working as I need?

First, in the WP back-end I created and published a blank page (using a custom template) that is a required part of this formula I concocted.

Each time a new page is created in the WP back-end, the blank page (the custom template php file) needs to grab and display 'object1' from that newly created page. So any time a new page is created in the WP back-end, 'object1' of that new page will be pulled into the published page. How do I achieve this? Here is the code I am working with:

```
<?php the_field('object1', /*code for any newly created page rather than a specific number*/ ); ?>
```

What is the code to input after 'object1',  for any newly created page?

I learned through trial and error these don't produce the result I'm needing:

```
<?php the_field('object1'); ?>
```

^^ The above code resulted in getting 'object1' from the current page only, which is the blank page (custom template).

```
<?php the_field('object1', 3 ); ?>
```

^^ The above code resulted in getting 'object1' from the page with post id number 3 in the url.

```
<?php the_field('object1', $post->ID ); ?>
```

^^ The above code resulted in getting 'object1' from the current page only, which is the blank page (custom template).

Many thanks for any guidance given.

---

`$post->ID` calls for current page, but what is the code to call for any new page created and published in WordPress?

Comment: Are you trying to show `object` for *all* pages, or just the latest?

Comment: Bari, if the current answers to your question don't solve the problem, try to explain it better, and _wait_. Don't vandalize your question, and don't delete it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the ID of the every published page, then you need to query them all. To do so, write a simple query that grabs every page from database:

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 // Query all pages
];

$pages = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Now, run a loop through the queried pages and use their IDs. It's better to use `get_the_ID()` to retrieve the ID, instead of messing with the globals. Here's how to:

```
// Define an array to use in the loop
$ids = array();
// Run a loop and check if it has any pages/posts
if( $pages->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $pages->have_posts() ) {
        $pages->the_post();
        // Add the current page ID to the array
        $ids[] = get_the_ID();
    }
}
```

Now you have an array of page IDs inside the `$ids` variable.

Comment: Setting `'fields' => 'ids'` on the query will have it return an array of IDs without the need for a loop.

Comment: You should replace `$ids[] = get_the_ID();` with `the_field('object1', get_the_ID() );`, instead of copying the code inside the field. @Bari

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the ID of the last page published, there's no single function for it. You'll need to retrieve the latest pages with `get_posts()` and get the ID of the first result. `get_posts()` already sorts by date, so all you need to do is tell it to get pages, not posts, only get one, and just get the ID:

```
$page_ids = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'fields'      => 'ids',
) );
```

`get_posts()` returns an array, so we'll want to make sure that the results weren't empty, and if not use the first result:

```
$page_ids = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'fields'      => 'ids',
) );

if ( ! empty( $latest_page ) ) {
    the_field( 'object1', $latest_page[0] );
}
```

If you need to show the `object1` field for *all* pages, you can't just give `the_field()` a value for it to do that automatically. You need to retrieve the IDs for all posts then loop over them, outputting the field for each one. You do this by changing the number of posts to `-1` (infinite) and using a `foreach` loop:

```
$page_ids = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'fields'      => 'ids',
) );

foreach ( $page_ids as $page_id ) {
    the_field( 'object1', $page_id );
}
```

Comment: I meant they're essentially the same, Jack's just has more unnecessary code. You probably had a typo.

Comment: I honestly don't even understand what you're trying to do. Why is this code on every page, I thought you had a custom template just for showing the object1 of every page. If you only want to show the field for the current page, you've already answered that yourself in your question.

Comment: This is a really unusual way of doing it. There shouldn't need to be a page for the template that's being included. You can put `the_field()` in a template file, include it with `get_template_part()` and it will show the field for the current page. The included template doesn't need to be assigned to a page.

Comment: If this isn't the correct answer, then I don't understand the question as it's currently worded.